# How to find ipsw file on macOS Catalina

Tags: ios, itunes, catalina, ipsw

I have downloaded latest iOS on my iPhone and it's not installing. It says "no internet" while the internet is working on the device. So I decided to synchronize the iPhone and get access to the downloaded IPSW for the iOS device.

But in macOS Catalina I couldn't find the IPSW file under Library/iTunes/

Any ideas how can I retrieve the downloaded IPSW?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Where (which website) did you download the IPSW file from? For which version of iOS did you download the IPSW file.

Comment: macOS on iPhone ?? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: "macOS" comes from an incorrect edit. I've fixed it.

Comment: Can't provide a proper answer, as I don't have any machine that can run Catalina - The IPSW file won't be on the Mac if you downloaded it to your iPhone.  
You would need to re-download via iTunes on the Mac itself [assuming iTunes can even still do that on Catalina]. It would then be at `~/Library/iTunes/iPhone Software Updates/` not `/Library/iTunes/`, they're different locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to retrieve the ipsw file directly from the ios device because the device has already downloaded the file internally. There is no way to retrieve the ipsw file version from the iPhone itself - if you even could - it may not be compatible to work through the Mac. Instead you will need to redownload the file on the Mac instead

Comment: Can you give me some reference link to this please ?

Answer (score 3):

While downloading the file through Finder, Open terminal:

```
%lsof | grep ipsw
```

This command will show you the open ipsw file (which is being downloaded).

The path to find the downloaded ipsw file is:

```
/Users/Username/Library/iTunes/iPhone Software Updates/
```

Comment: I tried it's not showing when I download ipsw through iphone or ipad.

Comment: the command I valid only if you're downloading the IPSW file using iTunes in your Mac/PC.

Comment: Thanks. It should be `lsof | grep ipsw` without the `%` at the begining.